# Confused about workings of a Haskell list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell

I'm a new programmer and using Haskell. I've found a line of code called find that matches up a String with its corresponding pair in a list. Like so

```
find a b = [x|(y,x) <- b, a==y]
```

I don't understand fully what this program is saying, for the list comprehension, as I've never seen the `x|(y,x)` used in such a way before, I've mainly seen it used as `x|x` or `x|x^2`. So, does this mean that find the string `A`, from your input list `B` = a list comprehension of `x`, where `x` is a pair of `(String, Char)` from your `B`, and for which the `y` equals your inputted `a`? A little confused here.

Answer (score 7):

I would pronounce that comprehension

> The list of all `x` such that `(y, x)` is drawn from `b` and `a == y`.

Another way to read it, more sequentially:

> Draw pairs `(y, x)` from `b`. For each such pair, check whether `a == y`. If so, produce `x`; otherwise, move on to the next one.

I should also note that the variable names are a bit confusing. It's idiomatic in Haskell to give lists or other containers plural names. So something more like

```
find a abs = [x | (y, x) <- abs, a == y]
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to view "`x|x`" as a thing. Rather, list comprehensions work like this:

> `[` expression to return `|` stuff to iterate over `]`

What your example basically says is "draw `(x, y)` from `b`, throw away anything which doesn't satisfy `a == y`, and then return `x`".

Answer (score 2):

Lets give you an example in order to visualize it:

```
find a b = [x|(y,x) <- b, a==y]
```

Let `a=2`, `b=[(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(2,7)]`

`(y,x)` will get each of `(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(2,7)` as a couple and check if the first element equals `2` (we said that `a` equals `2`). If True, the function will return the second element of that couple - `x`, and put it in a list with the rest of the answers.

So the output for that function would be `[4,7]`